# How to do a deep filtering of an object using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am having a multi level object of not sure how many levels it can have for example I am having a following object

```
[{
        "id": "1234",
        "desc": "sample1",
        "items": [{
            "item1": "testItem1",
            "item2": "testItem2"
        }]
    },
    {
        "id": "3456",
        "desc": "sample2",
        "items": [{
            "item1": "testItem12",
            "item2": "testItem23"
        }]
    }
]
```

How can we do a deep search for a string in pure javascript so that if the search string matches any of the values in the above object should return its respective object level.

for example If I search for "sample" it should return both the objects and if I search for "1234" it should return only one object. Is there a way we can search for the string with out passing the key and value pair we are searching? search string can be any where in the object. please help me with the logic.

lets say if I search with either "sample" or "testItem1" It should return me both the object from the parent level as it matches in both and If I search for "testItem23" then it should return me the complete 2nd object from the parent level.

Comment: Take a look at `Object.keys` and `Object.values`.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal

Comment: You might need to recursively check the values of the object for each value that is not a primitive. You can do it without recursion, which is likely more efficient but also more code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a simple iterative approach using a stack to walk your structure and build the result array:

```js
const find = (needle, haystack) => {
  const result = [];
  const stack = [[haystack, haystack]];

  while (stack.length) {
    const [curr, parent] = stack.pop();

    for (const o of curr) {
      for (const k in o) {
        if (Array.isArray(o[k])) {
          stack.push([o[k], o]);
        } 
        else if (o[k].includes(needle)) {
          result.push("items" in o ? o : parent);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  return result;
};

const data = [{
    "id": "1234",
    "desc": "sample1",
    "items": [{
      "item1": "testItem1",
      "item2": "testItem2"
    }]
  },
  {
    "id": "3456",
    "desc": "sample2",
    "items": [{
      "item1": "testItem12",
      "item2": "testItem23"
    }]
  }
];

console.log(find("sample", data));
console.log(find("1234", data));
console.log(find("testItem12", data));
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution @ggorlen , is there a way we can return the parent object if there is string match?? currently if I search for "testItem12" it is returning the items array object.

Comment: If you return the parent instead of the current object, you'll return `data` twice instead of `data[0]` and `data[1]` for the `"sample"` search. Is that your intention, or do you want to return the nearest parent that has an `id` key or similar?

Comment: The *includes* method is only available on strings and arrays. If the values in the objects are anything else, say numbers, objects or booleans, this approach fails.

Comment: @RobG this looks basically like JSON, so I think it's a reasonable assumption to make that the parameter structure's types are known well enough to avoid a bunch of type checks. If not, you can add `else if (o[k].includes && o[k].includes(needle)) {`.

Comment: yes sir, if we search for "sample" it should return the array of data and if we search for "testItem1" it should return the array of data with "id" level as parent object. will that be possible?

Comment: @krishnateja That's possible, but I'd recommend posting a more complete and complex i/o with explanation that illustrates what your expected outcome is a bit more fully. I'd hate to cook up another example only to find it's missing another requirement that went unsaid. While you're at it, feel free to confirm possible key/value types.

Comment: Sure, so if I search for "sample" it should return this way 0:{id: "1234", desc: "sample1", items: Array(1)}
1:{id: "3456", desc: "sample2", items: Array(1)}  and if I search for "testItem1" it should return the same as that text matches the string in both objects.

Comment: @ggorlen—JSON is not just strings. I don't see how type testing can be avoided where the condition may require a string–specific test (such as *includes* or *indexOf*). And you're already testing for arrays. ;-)

Comment: @krishnateja—you need to put the additional information in your question.

Comment: @RobG I'll throw in the `.includes &&` check if it seems like it'll be an issue, or handle other types as requested, but the OP wants to search in what looks like a predictable and regular structure. Should we over-engineer? I don't think so, but your point is reasonable. I mean, `for (const o of curr) {` will crash if the parameter is `undefined` or isn't an array. Should I do a conditional there as well or just assume the caller gave me an appropriate argument?

Comment: @ggorlen—I've added an answer with come checks. It's not clear to me what the OP really needs, the question is poorly asked and consequently not really worth answering until it's clarified. Over engineering for some is robust code to others. ;-)

Comment: @RobG It's not over-engineered if it's necessary. The great thing about SO is you get contrasting viewpoints, opinions and answers which benefits everyone, so thanks for weighing in.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach which utilizes js only. 
The idea is to filter the main array and inside for each object to flatten the values via recursion. Then use another filter with `indexOf` to match the actual property value inside the flattened values array ...

```js
var data = [{ "id": "1234", "desc": "sample1", "items": [{ "item1": "testItem1", "item2": "testItem2", "item3": [{ "item1": "testItemA", "item2": "testItemB" }] }] }, { "id": "3456", "desc": "sample2", "items": [{ "item1": "testItem12", "item2": "testItem23" }] } ]

const flattenValues = (o, values = []) => !(Object.values(o).forEach(x => (Array.isArray(x) || typeof x == 'object') ? [...flattenValues(x, values)] : values.push(x))) && values
const textSearch = (v, d) => d.filter(x => flattenValues(x).filter(y => y.indexOf(v) >= 0).length)

console.log(textSearch('sample', data))
console.log(textSearch('1234', data))
console.log(textSearch('testItem1', data))
console.log(textSearch('testItem12', data))
```

**More details:**

The `flattenValues` function for example would return for the object with id `1234` an array of the flattened values like this for each object:

```
['1234', 'sample1', 'testItem1', 'testItem2' ...]
```

Then the `textSearch` would use `filter` and inside compare if the filter of the result of:

```
flattenValues(x).filter(y => y.indexOf(v) >= 0)
```

returns `truthy` value

Answer (score 1):

If you need to deal with values other than arrays and strings, you'll need to test the values before comparing. You might compare the value passed in so you only test property values with the right type.

This just returns objects that are elements of the original data array. If you want some other object, you'll need to provide the logic.

```js
var arr = [{
    "id": "1234",
    "desc": "sample1",
    "items": [{
      "item1": "testItem1",
      "item2": "testItem2"
    }]
  },
  {
    "id": "3456",
    "desc": "sample2",
    "items": [{
      "item1": "testItem12",
      "item2": "testItem23"
    }]
  }
];

function findInObjArray(array, value) {
  var found = [];

  // Helper to search obj for value
  function findInObj(obj, value) {
    return Object.values(obj).some(
      v =>
        // If v is an object, call recursively
        typeof v == 'object' && v != 'null'? findInObj(v, value) :
        // If string, check if value is part of v
        typeof v == 'string'? v.indexOf(value) >= 0 :
        // Check numbers, make NaN == NaN
        typeof v == 'number'? v === value || isNaN(v) && isNaN(value):
        // Otherwise look for strict equality: null, undefined, function, boolean
        v === value
    );
  };

  array.forEach(function(obj) {
    if (findInObj(obj, value)) found.push(obj);
  })
  return found;
}

console.log(
  findInObjArray(arr, 'testItem23')
);
```